# Integrating $e$ over all positive numbers (0-inf) - why doesn't this converge to -1?

Tags: integration, exponential-function, exponentiation

It's been a while since I looked at calculus, so I'm not sure what mistake I'm making here. I saw this in a text recently:

$$450\int_0^{\infty} e^{-.7t} dt = 450/0.7$$

I understand $e^{-\infty}$ is just zero, since $e$ is simply a number. I also get that $e^0$ is just $1$, as any number to the zero-th power is 1.

So why isn't the integral of $e^{-.7t} = 0 - 1 = -1$, instead of 1/exponent?

Comment: You have to find the antiderivative first, before you plug in the numbers.

Comment: Do the substitution $u=-.7t$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int \mathrm{e}^{-0.7 t} \,\mathrm{d}t = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-0.7 t}}{-0.7} +C  \text{.}  $$
You've forgotten the denominator.  Then
$$\left(\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-0.7 t}}{-0.7}\right) - \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-0.7 \cdot0}}{-0.7} = \frac{0}{-0.7} - \frac{1}{-0.7} = \frac{1}{0.7} \text{.}$$
(Then recall that there is a factor of $450$ in the original expression.)